# Override email template in django rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

How can I override the reset password email template from django rest-auth?

Here are the urls I'm talking about:

```
 url(
    regex=r'^contrib/password_reset/$',
    view=password_reset,
    name='password_reset'
),

url(r'^api/rest-auth/password/reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
    name='rest_password_reset'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom `PassswordResetSerializer` first and made it work in the settings.

For further information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111127/2142093). I did that and it worked. The only difference would be that I saved my template in this route: `/templates/account/registration/password_reset_email.html`. I have a txt version aswell.