# How to override django allauth email templates

Tags: django-templates, django-allauth, django-email

I'm using `allauth` version `0.35.0` and I want to override email templates to make my desired HTML template for them. No problem with `allauth` login and SignUp and etc. pages But I can't find any template for emails.

It's just a `.txt` file in path `/templates/account/email/`. But How can I set `HTML`message for `allauth` tasks like changing password and etc. for their email messages?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ooops! Shame on me!

in [this part of `allauth` documentation](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/common/email.html) This said that:

> Emails sent (e.g. in case of password forgotten or email confirmation) can be altered by providing your own templates. Templates are named as follows:
>
> `account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt`
>
> `account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt`
>
> In case you want to include an HTML representation, add an HTML template as follows:
>
> `account/email/email_confirmation_message.html`

So making `email_confirmation_message.html` in my own template and using template variables which are used in the `email_confirmation_message.txt` solved the problem.

Comment: However, this question still able to help others. Some django newbies need this post.

Comment: Helped me indeed. I'm new to Django and wasn't really understanding what the context for overriding was. :)

Comment: @jsbls I'm happy it helped. Happy Coding, And Happy New Year :)

Comment: Same!! Hope you have a django-related bug-free year. :)