# customising django allauth templates

Tags: django, django-allauth

mostly trying to modify the email verification that is sent on sign-up following the allauth documentation the sent email is modified when i change email_confirmation_message.txt but when i want to use an html representaion the documentation says to use email_confirmation_message.html but it is not recognized and instead it sends the default email or if i include both it only sneds the text one and ignores the html

email_confirmation_message.html :

```
{% extends "account/email/base_message.txt" %}
{% load account %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}{% autoescape off %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}
<!doctype html>
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
                                <title>Snippet - GoSNippets</title>
                                <link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                                <link href='' rel='stylesheet'>
                                
    
                                <script type='text/javascript' src=''></script>
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
                            </head>
                            <body oncontextmenu='return false' class='snippet-body'>
                            <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;"> We're thrilled to have you here! Get ready to dive into your new account. </div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">We're excited to have you get started on {{ site_domain }}. First, you need to confirm your account. Just press the button below.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 30px 60px 30px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#FFA73B"><a href={{ activate_url }} target="_blank" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #FFA73B; display: inline-block;">Confirm Account</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr> <!-- COPY -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">If that doesn't work, copy and paste the following link in your browser:</p>
                    </td>
                </tr> <!-- COPY -->
                
</table>
                            <script type='text/javascript'></script>
                            </body>
                        </html>
{% endblocktrans %}{% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override django allauth email templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684839/how-to-override-django-allauth-email-templates)

Comment: Also avoid all JavaScript in EMAIL message.

Comment: i still don't understand how to make email_confirmation_message.html work

Answer (score 0):

ok,so i figured it out. you have to also change email_confirmation_signup_message.txt
to email_confirmation_signup_message.html and inside it change `{% include "account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt" %}` to `{% include "account/email/email_confirmation_message.html" %}`

Comment: Why do you need to use `{% include "account/email/email_confirmation_message.html" %}`? All what you need is to move template to the right folder. `templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.html`