# How to customize a URL to reset password in an email template?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django Rest Auth with Django All Auth.

When I hit an endpoint `/rest-auth/password/reset/ (POST)` I receive an email includes a URL to reset a password.

But the URL doesn't work, because a domain is always `example.com` and `uid` `token` don't work well like below...

```
http://example.com/password/reset/confirm/(%3FPMzQ%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP5ku-afb8832e99157c02f452%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/$
```

I've overridden a PasswordResetSerializer to use my email template referring [to this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078367/resetting-password-of-user-django-rest-auth)

How can I solve this situation?

---

Here are the codes:

serializers.py

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer


class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):

    def get_email_options(self):
        print("check override")

        return {
            'email_template_name': 'password_reset_key_message.txt',

        }
```

password_reset_key_message.txt

```
A password reset has been requested.
Click the link below to continue.

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

If I change a part of `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` to `{{ password_reset_url }}` the email doesn't include any URL

---

When I add `'domain_override'` in `def get_email_options(self)` like berow,

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer


class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):

    def get_email_options(self):
        print("check override")

        return {
            'domain_override': 'localhost:8000',
            'email_template_name': 'password_reset_key_message.txt',

        }
```

The URL became like below,

```
http://localhost:8000/password/reset/confirm/(%3FPMzQ%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP5ku-afb8832e99157c02f452%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/$
```

In this case, I can specify a domain, but `uid` and `token` still don't work...

---

python: 3.7.5

Django:2.2.2

django-allauth:0.41.0

django-rest-auth:0.9.5

djangorestframework:3.12.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152730/6013354 try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to change the example.com to another domain you will need to change the domain on the database. To do that create a superuser by `python manage.py createsuperuser` and then go to the /admin page. Then click on the change button on the Sites option. And then you will see 'example.com' just click on it and change it to your expected domain. And yes, you don't need the so critical way you specified.

**UPDATE**

The actual answer that worked for the questioner is to do the things mentioned above and also replace `path('accounts_api/password/reset/confirm/(.....` to `re_path(r'^accounts_api/password/reset/confirm/(.....`
in urls.py

Comment: Thank you for your help, I could change the domain name following your way, But `uid` and `token` still don't work in URL... like `http://localhost:8000/password/reset/confirm/(%3FPMzY%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP5ku-d3e591f48bf611ef3f2f%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/$`

Comment: It would be helpful for me to understand if you could tell me if tried a newly generated or the old link?

Comment: if I click newly link, I get Page not found (404).

Comment: I am not understanding. I have used django allauth only and password reset was successful without even creating any files.

Comment: And yes html templates and subject text also works without any serializer.

Comment: After I change url.py `path('accounts_api/password/reset/confirm/(.....` to `re_path(r'^accounts_api/password/reset/confirm/(.....` I could receive a email with working URL.