# How to customize django rest auth email context

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

Similar to this question
[How to customize django rest auth password reset email content/template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897834/how-to-customize-django-rest-auth-password-reset-email-content-template/52111127)
I would like to customize password reset (and other) emails automatically send by django rest auth. It perfectly works to use custom email templates with an custom serializer:

```py
class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    def get_email_options(self):
        return {
            'domain_override': settings.FRONTEND_URL,
            'email_template_name': 'registration/custom_reset_email.txt',
            'html_email_template_name': 'registration/custom_reset_email.html',
        }
```

But additionally to customized templates I want to add custom **context**. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PasswordResetSerializer` uses the `PasswordResetForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`. The `save()` method of the `PasswordResetForm` accepts a parameter `extra_email_context`. So all you need to do is add `extra_email_context` to the dictionary your return:

```
def get_email_options(self):
    extra_context = {...}  # your extra context parameters
    return {
            'domain_override': settings.FRONTEND_URL,
            'email_template_name': 'registration/custom_reset_email.txt',
            'html_email_template_name': 'registration/custom_reset_email.html',
            'extra_email_context': extra_context
        }
```

Just make sure your `extra_context` doesn't override existing keys: `email`, `token`, `domain`, `site_name`, `user`, `uid` and `protocol` are already in use.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.