# dj_rest_auth password reset serializer is not working

Tags: django, dj-rest-auth, customserializer

I have followed [this](https://medium.com/@etentuk/django-rest-framework-how-to-edit-reset-password-link-in-dj-rest-auth-with-dj-allauth-installed-c54bae36504e) guide and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904906/cutomize-dj-rest-auth-password-reset-email) stackoverflow post but for some reason none of them seem to pick up anything from my custom serializer for password reset. I have implemented the custom serializer like this:

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import check_user_email
from dj_rest_auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "password/reset/confirm/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/",
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name="password_reset_confirm",
    ),
    path("", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
    # path("registration/", include("dj_rest_auth.registration.urls")),
    path("check-user-email/", check_user_email),
]
```

accounts/serializer.py

```
from allauth.account.utils import (
    filter_users_by_email,
    user_pk_to_url_str,
    user_username,
)
from allauth.utils import build_absolute_uri
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.forms import default_token_generator
from allauth.account import app_settings
from dj_rest_auth.forms import AllAuthPasswordResetForm
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers


class CustomAllAuthPasswordResetForm(AllAuthPasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Invalid email should not raise error, as this would leak users
        for unit test: test_password_reset_with_invalid_email
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        self.users = filter_users_by_email(email, is_active=True)
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]

    def save(self, request, **kwargs):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        token_generator = kwargs.get("token_generator", default_token_generator)

        for user in self.users:
            temp_key = token_generator.make_token(user)

            path = f"I basically want to add frontend url here/{user_pk_to_url_str(user)}/{temp_key}/"
            url = build_absolute_uri(request, path)
            # Values which are passed to password_reset_key_message.txt
            context = {
                "current_site": current_site,
                "user": user,
                "password_reset_url": url,
                "request": request,
                "path": path,
            }

            if (
                app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD
                != app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL
            ):
                context["username"] = user_username(user)
            get_adapter(request).send_mail(
                "account/email/password_reset_key", email, context
            )

        return self.cleaned_data["email"]


class MyPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    def validate_email(self, value):
        # use the custom reset form
        self.reset_form = CustomAllAuthPasswordResetForm(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.reset_form.errors)

        return value
```

This is settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config("DEBUG", cast=bool)
isProd = (
    config("ENVIRONMENT") != "local"
)  # true of isProd == "production" or isProd == "staged"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config("HOSTS", cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(",")])
ORIGINS = config("ORIGINS", cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(",")])
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ORIGINS
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ORIGINS

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "accounts",
    "api",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "dj_rest_auth",
    "corsheaders",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "dj_rest_auth.registration",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "accounts.middleware.VerifyTokenByHttpOnlyCookie",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "server.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "server.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

# Database
if isProd:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
            "USER": config("DB_USER"),
            "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASS"),
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": "",
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
        }
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

SITE_ID = 1

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = config("EMAIL_VERIFICATION")

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("APP_EMAIL_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("APP_EMAIL_PASS")

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "rest_framework.views.exception_handler",
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 25,
}

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.MyPasswordResetSerializer",
}

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CONN_MAX_AGE = None if isProd else 0  # persistent database connections in prod/stage

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = isProd
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = isProd
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = isProd

REST_AUTH = {
    "USE_JWT": True,
    "JWT_AUTH_COOKIE": "jwt-auth",
    "JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE": "jwt-refresh",
    "JWT_AUTH_SECURE": isProd,
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=15),
}
```

I am using dj-rest-auth==4.0.1, django-allauth==0.54.0 what am I doing wrong! Did they changed some settings!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was how I was using the serializers in the settings.py! All the articles online refers that the serializer should be imported like this:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.MyPasswordResetSerializer",
}
```

But nope you have to do it like this:

```
REST_AUTH = {
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.MyPasswordResetSerializer",
}
```

Change REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS to REST_AUTH and it should work. I think dj_rest_auth package changed recently how you should use the variables! And instantly every other article became obsolete. It would be so much easier if they detailly documented this exact setting on how to use custom serializer for password-reset/account-confirm-email in their own doc. Then I didn't have to waste my 8h time debugging different things! May be they did, comment it if anyone can find this.